# How to select the average of columns "x" selected with the max of columns "y" grouped by 15 minutes intervals?

Tags: mysql

I have a table that looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `visits` (
  `idsite` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `idvisit` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `server_time` datetime NOT NULL,
  `actions` float DEFAULT NULL,
)
```

I want to get the average of `actions` in the interval of 15 minutes in which the sum of distinct `idvisit` is maximum.

I started by doing this:

```
select max(counted), server_time 
  from (select count(distinct idvisit) as counted, server_time 
     from visits group by year(server_time), month(server_time), day(server_time), ( 4 * HOUR( server_time ) + FLOOR( MINUTE( server_time ) / 15 )) ) as counts;
```

I got the maximum of visits but the wrong `server_time`. I have no idea how to get the hole concerned row in order to select the average of actions in the right interval.

Sample data:

```
+--------+---------+--------------+---------------------+
| idsite | idvisit | actions      | server_time         |
+--------+---------+--------------+---------------------+
|      1 |       1 |           14 | 2015-09-15 22:06:57 |
|      1 |       2 |           60 | 2015-09-16 22:09:41 |
|      1 |       3 |            5 | 2015-09-16 22:09:54 |
|      1 |       3 |           40 | 2015-09-16 22:16:58 |
|      1 |       4 |            6 | 2015-09-16 22:19:04 |
|      1 |       5 |            7 | 2015-09-16 22:40:53 |
|      1 |       6 |            1 | 2015-09-16 23:01:41 |
|      1 |       6 |            5 | 2015-09-16 23:08:54 |
|      1 |       7 |           10 | 2015-09-16 23:19:58 |
|      1 |       8 |            6 | 2015-09-16 23:26:14 |
|      1 |       9 |            7 | 2015-09-16 23:48:53 |
+--------+---------+--------------+---------------------+
```

The expected result:

```
+--------------+---------------------+
| AVG(actions) | DATE(server_time)   |
+--------------+---------------------+
|        26.33 | 2015-09-15          |
+--------------+---------------------+
```

which correspond to the first 15 minutes in which there is a maximum of distinct idvisit.

Can somebody help?

Comment: show some sample data, say a dozen rows or less, the expected results, and discuss any tricky edge conditions. A sqlfiddle would be nice, so we don't have to do the legwork

Comment: -Based on sample data, how do you get `26.33` and `2015-09-15`? I think the interval between `2015-09-16 22:09:41` and `2015-09-19 22:19:04` is the one with maximum distinct idvisit so the average is `(60+5+40+6)/4=27.75`, right?

Comment: forgot to mention that intervals should be delimited by :00, :15, :30, :45

Comment: Why is actions float?

Comment: It was just for simplification, I used other column types and names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to count idVisits between fixed 15 minutes interval:
something like

```
00:00:00 - 00:14:59 -- x values
00:15:00 - 00:29:59 -- y values
00:30:00 - 00:44:59 -- z values
00:45:00 - 00:59:59 -- w values
```

etc

You can use the following sql:

```
   SELECT
      COUNT(DISTINCT idvisit) AS counted
    , AVG(actions) AS average
    , FROM_UNIXTIME(FLOOR( UNIX_TIMESTAMP(server_time)/900 ) * 900) AS final_server_time
   FROM
      visits
   GROUP BY
      final_server_time
   ORDER BY
      counted DESC, final_server_time
   LIMIT 1
```

Example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/36a80f/30

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks !